# IBM Worklight 6.1 - adapter parameters size limit

Tags: parameters, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst, limits

I am trying to send a base64 image via Worklight adapter.

I want to know which parameters size can the adapter handle?

Can I use a 8MB Image and convert it to base64 (let's say it will become 12 Mega Byte on 1 parameter), and then send it successfully to worklight adapter?  or there is a length limit for the adapter parameters?

Comment: Did you try before asking?

Comment: No, I want to know if there is a known size limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, there shouldn't be any limitation.

But... I think you need to re-think why you would want to send a 12mb-sized image to your app (to the device, actually).

1. Load time-wise it will be slow and create a bottleneck
2. I don't know your scenario, but why not send a link to the image and load that?
3. Why not use Cordova File API for file transfer (which is more correct, because adapters were not meant for data transfer like this - instead you can use File API + a servlet that will talk with the database)

Comment: Yes I agree, sending 12MB parameter is not the right way to it, but I wanted just to verify feasibility