# MobileFirst 7.0 image upload and javascript adapter parameters size limit

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

It seems that there is already a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733229/ibm-worklight-6-1-adapter-parameters-size-limit) on so and we meet with it indeed.

We are calling adapters and sending encoded base64 strings to the backend. All things works fine with tiny pictures less than 1Mb. But if the image size is larger (eg. 4Mb, just a ordinary Photo from the end-user's iPhone album), it stucked with adapter invoking errors. I also find clues after debugging that, in condition with uploading large image the adapter will never step into the backend business logic but in the condition the tiny pics can.

Some of the code snippets could be like below:

```
var base64Str = "";
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    base64Str = e.target.result;
    preview.setAttribute('src', base64Str );
    uploadImage(picUuid, base64Str);
}

//calling the HTTP image upload adapter
function uploadImage(uuid, base64Data){
    WL.Logger.debug("base64Data:" + base64Data);
    var invocationData = {
            adapter : 'ImageUploadAdapter',
            procedure : 'uploadImage',
            parameters : [uuid, base64Data]
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
        onSuccess : uploadImageSuccess,
        onFailure : uploadImageFailure,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MobileFirst Platform 7.0 introduced Java adapters in addition to the existing JavaScript adapters.

With Java adapters there is no such limitation for the file sizes that can be operated on when using JavaScript adapters and data can be handled as Binary rather than encoded to base64, etc.

In other words, there is no multi-part support in JavaScript adapters, whereas in Java adapters (that are based on the JAX-RS specifications) you can.

You can read more about it here:

- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/adapter-framework-overview/

Comment: In the other question, I saw you wrote "Basically, there shouldn't be any limitation", but it is indeedly limited, right?

Comment: With JavaScript adapters, sort of, yes, because it's not mean as a way to "stream" data for long durations.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function encodeImageFileAsURL() {

    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
    if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
      var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

      var fileReader = new FileReader();

      fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
        var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

        var newImage = document.createElement('img');
        newImage.src = srcData;
        alert(srcData);
        document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML = newImage.outerHTML;
        alert("Converted Base64 version is " + document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML);
        console.log("Converted Base64 version is " + document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML);
        uploadImage(srcData);
      }
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
  }

    //calling the HTTP image upload adapter
    function uploadImage(srcData){
        WL.Logger.debug("srcData:" + srcData);
        var invocationData = {
                adapter : 'ImageUploadAdapter',
                procedure : 'uploadImage',
                parameters : [srcData]
        };

        WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
            onSuccess : uploadImageSuccess,
            onFailure : uploadImageFailure,
        });
    }
```